# How to bring back sites and resource document into the resource reservation database

Tags: calendar, lotus-notes, resources

For some reason, Some of my sites and resource documents have disapeared from the resource and reservation database, but they are still in Domino Directory so users can book using the mail calendar.

As my users want to book using the resource reservation database I need to find a way to restore these documents into the database

I am using IBM Notes client & server 9

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new resource in the directory. This should appear in the reservation database after some time. If this works, cut the resources from the Domino directory that are missing and paste them back afterwards.